# Error 404 call controller from view

Tags: magento-1.9, 404-page

Thanks in advance.

The problem I have is that when I call a controller it gives me a 404 error.

I have already done clear cache, permissions 777 and 644 to folders and disable and activate the created module.

I attach the code in case you see any errors.

config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
        <modules>
                <Mymodule_GeneratePdf>
                        <version>1.0</version>
                </Mymodule_GeneratePdf>
        </modules>
        <frontend>
                <routers>
                        <mymodule_generatePdf>
                                <use>standard</use>
                                <args>
                                        <module>Mymodule_GeneratePdf</module>
                                        <frontName>generatepdf</frontName>
                                </args>
                        </mymodule_generatePdf>
                </routers>
        </frontend>
</config>
```

controllers/IndexController.php

```
class Mymodule_GeneratePdf_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action
{
    public function PdfAgreementsAction()
    {
        $numDoc = $_POST['numdoc'];
        Mage::log($numDoc);
    }
}
```

etc/modules/Mymodule_GeneratePdf.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Mymodule_GeneratePdf>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </Mymodule_GeneratePdf>
    </modules>
</config>
```

call by phtml

```
  function getPdf(num){
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: "<?php echo $this->getUrl('generatepdf/index/PdfAgreements'); // Mage::getUrl('generatepdf/index/PdfAgreements'); ?>",
        type: "POST",
        data: { numdoc: num}
     }).done(function(data) {
console.log(data);
});
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Your controller should be inside controllers/ folder not controller/

Comment: folder name at controller should be `controllers` instead of `controller`

Comment: Sorry is topographical error the folder is controllers

Answer (score 0):

Please pass form_key in the ajax call

```
function getPdf(num){
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: "<?php echo $this->getUrl('generatepdf/index/PdfAgreements'); // Mage::getUrl('generatepdf/index/PdfAgreements'); ?>",
        type: "POST",
        data: { numdoc: num, form_key:<?php echo Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getFormKey() ?>}
     }).done(function(data) {
console.log(data);
});
}
```

Thanks and let me know if you have any query.

Comment: Added form_key and still giving error 404

Comment: Please try to make pdfAgreements insted of PdfAgreements at all places.

Comment: Still with the same error